# Checking which file I'm dragging

Tags: c++, qt

I've created a Qt app which allows me to drag files on to it (on a listView). Now I'd like to drag out some of those files from this list but I don't know how to check which files I'm dragging. Could anyone tell me how to do it? (I'm using dragEnterEvent, dragDropEvent, and dragLeaveEvent)

Comment: what means "drag out"? You have a QListView with items. And you want to delete items from this list view by draging them. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @geotavros yes, you do understand this correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass QListView and reimplement its mousePressEvent. This is how you get the QModelIndex of the item you're going to drag:

```
void MyView::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event ) {
  QModelIndex item_you_going_to_drag = indexAt(event->pos());
```

Then you construct QMimeData and QDrag objects, see this example:
[Draggable Icons Example](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/draganddrop-draggableicons.html#id-89d1d95a-a201-4d23-99c6-09b30c0b11f3)